# PHP to PDF tick checkboxes

Tags: php, pdf, checkbox, pdf-form, fdf

Why isn't my "PHP to PDF" code not ticking checkboxes?
What am I doing wrong?

My pdf fields

```
FieldType: Button  
FieldName: aaaa  
FieldFlags: 0  
FieldValue: Off  
FieldJustification: Left  
FieldStateOption: Off  
FieldStateOption: Yes
```

Here is my PHP code:

```
require('fpdm.php');

$fields = array(
  'POPMLSAddress' => $_POST['Text3'],
  'aaaa'=> 'Yes'
);

$pdf = new FPDM('check1.pdf');
$pdf->Load($fields, false); // second parameter: false if field values are in ISO-8859-1, true if UTF-8
$pdf->Merge();
$pdf->Output();

ob_end_flush();
```

In PDF file, checkbox have to be checked with tick.

Answer (score 0):

**i try to filling out PDF forms using PHP and PDFtk Server instead FPDM.**
there are many methods and php libraries to do pdfForm filling ... 
for button controls editing with php to pdf form this method is life saving.[dragon kiss](https://github.com/lavary/pdf-form)

```
$data = [
    'first_name' => 'John',
    'last_name'  => 'Smith',
    'occupation' => 'Teacher',
    'age'        => '45',
    'gender'     => 'male'
];

$pdf = new PdfForm('form.pdf', $data);

$pdf->flatten()
    ->save('output.pdf')
    ->download();
```

Comment: above code working fine on local host. 
on server its getting strange error?

some site not allowed requesting the same file twice
http://www.sevety.com/final/

 is this server issue?